# Distinguish between mouse click and finger tap in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing an Angular app and would like to support both desktop / laptops and touch devices.

For one of the features I'm implementing I would like to be able to distinguish whether the user clicked or touched an element and trigger different handlers.

What's the simplest way to do that? I was thinking of doing User-Agent detection in the server and return different JS files if the user has a touch device but that seems nasty / overkill.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this fiddle should give you a good idea, specifically these listeners:

```
on-touch="clickedOrTouched(4)"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guillaumebiton/R8mmR/6/

The 'on-touch' event appears to support mouse clicks as well.

[EDIT] - It looks like I misread your question.  I think you could add listeners to the ngMousedown or nfMouseup events to determine if a it is a clicks vs touch

Comment: Actually, take a close look and play around with that fiddle, I think it does account for separating functionality

Comment: The tricky part is that for a mouse it goes: mousedown -> mouseup -> click, whereas touch has all kind of touchstart / touchmove / touchcancel / touchend and then it also triggers clicks. But I guess I'll have to implement my own directive that somehow wraps this together. Too bad there's no out of the box option. :P

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps you, but in newer versions of angularJS (the 1.1.x development branch which will become angularJS 1.2) there is a new module named ngTouch (recently renamed from ngMobile). It supports various touch-related functions. Check the source code for this module at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/tree/master/src/ngTouch.